# Frequency adverb locations

Tags: grammar, adverbs

When using frequency adverbs like `ぜんぜん,あまり,よく` and so forth. Where is the correct location in the sentence to structure it?

In my Genki I textbook it says the sentence structure is **Topic Frequency Time Goal Verb** such as

> 私は よく しちじに うちに かえります

But I've also seen in my book:

> スーさんは、 しゃしんを ぜんぜん とりませんでした。
>   わたしは、こどものとき よくハンバーガーを たべました。

Where the frequency adverb is not following that structure and is sometimes before or after the particle. It's looking like I can stick it almost anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: For the most part, you can.  There probably is a right/wrong way to do it, grammatically, but colloquially it will bounce around, just as you've illustrated.

Answer (score 2):

> 私は よく しちじに うちに かえります

It is safe to place the frequency adverb before what it directly modifies. In this sentence what happens よく is しちじにうちにかえる not just うちにかえる ("Going home" would happen oftener than よく.) so placing よく before しちじにうちにかえります would sound more natural.

> スーさんは、 しゃしんを ぜんぜん とりませんでした。

「スーさんは、 ぜんぜん しゃしんを とりませんでした。」 would also be fine.
ぜんぜん modifies しゃしんをとりませんでした or とりませんでした (What Sue didn't do at all was しゃしんをとる or とる)

> わたしは、こどものとき よくハンバーガーを たべました。

Here what happened よく is ハンバーガーをたべた not こどものときハンバーガーをたべた. よくハンバーガーをたべた happened in こどものとき. わたしは、こどものとき ハンバーガーを よくたべました would also be acceptable (but よく might sound like '(eat) a lot', not 'often', when placed before たべました). You could also say こどものとき、わたしはよくハンバーガーをたべました.

But when you talk casually you could place it almost anywhere.

> ぜんぜん、スーさん(は)、しゃしん(を)とりませんでしたよ。
>   スーさん(は)、ぜんぜん、しゃしん(を)とりませんでしたよ。
>   スーさん(は)、しゃしん(を)ぜんぜんとりませんでしたよ。
>   スーさん(は)、しゃしん(を)とりませんでしたよ、ぜんぜん。
>   しゃしん(を)、ぜんぜんとりませんでしたよ、スーさん(は)。
>   スーさん(は)、ぜんぜんとりませんでしたよ、しゃしん(を)。
>   etc.